# How to create text around a circle (Circle of Fifths)

Tags: html, css

**Level of expertise in HTML & CSS:** Beginner

**Goal:** Use HTML & CSS to add text that surrounds the outside of a circle just like this one:

Circle of Fifths

[image]

**Progress:** https://codepen.io/annieg4123/pen/GGPayQ

**Issue:** When I position one letter, it affects the positioning of the others. For instance, if I add `left: 855px;`to `#Gb-Fsharp`, the position of `#C` is changed.

**Question:** Why does this happen? Is my current way of positioning the letters incorrect? If so, what should I do instead?

Comment: u sould use absolute positioning or using js to calc the diff so to use as relative positioning

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the right id to the CSS file and give the fixed position of letters.
I created a sample of your issue https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKOyKQ

```
#circle {
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-radius: 50%;
   padding-bottom: 30%.......
```

Comment: When answering, please reproduce all your code directly on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your text got shifted because you are using relative positioning. Whenever you will add new text it will align according to that text. Suppose you have a text left-align:50px to then if you add new text in between then it will shift all the older texts and elements. so you have to give fixed position or absolute position to the text and elements.